# Why isn't flex element wrapping to second row with flex-wrap:wrap?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, row

I want to have a container flex div with 3 elements per row, problem is when I add the fourth element (it should automatically wrap to the second row), instead it stays on a single row and shrinks the other elemets. I enabled wrapping with flex-wrap: wrap;

Here is my code:

```html
<div class="border" style="width:100%; height:auto; position:relative; display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap; justify-content:flex-start; ">
  <div class="border" style="flex:1 1 33.33%; height:400px; margin-bottom:10px; margin-right:10px; text-align:center; padding:10px 10px;">
    <img src="https://images.petsmartassets.com/is/image/PetSmart/ARTHMB-HowMuchExerciseDoesMyDogNeed-20160818?$AR1104$" style="width:100%; height:70%; position:relative;">
    <a href="#">
      <h6 style="color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.6); font-weight:900; font-size:12px; margin-top:10px; ">HEALTH & CARE</h6>
    </a>
    <h5 style="font-weight:600;">How much exercise does my dog need?</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="border" style="flex:1 1 33.33%; height:400px; margin-bottom:10px; margin-right:10px; text-align:center; padding:10px 10px;">
    <img src="https://images.petsmartassets.com/is/image/PetSmart/ARTHMB-HomeToRoamFindTheRightDogForYourApartment-20160818?$AR1104$" style="width:100%; height:70%; position:relative;">
    <a href="#">
      <h6 style="color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.6); font-weight:900; font-size:12px; margin-top:10px; ">HEALTH & CARE</h6>
    </a>
    <h5 style="font-weight:600;">How much exercise does my dog need?</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="border" style="flex:1 1 33.33%; height:400px; margin-bottom:10px; text-align:center; padding:10px 10px;">
    <img src="https://images.petsmartassets.com/is/image/PetSmart/ARTHMB-GoDogGoCrateCarrierGateOrKennel-20160818?$AR1104$" style="width:100%; height:70%; position:relative;">
    <a href="#">
      <h6 style=" color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.6); font-weight:900; font-size:12px; margin-top:10px; ">HEALTH & CARE</h6>
    </a>
    <h5 style="font-weight:600;">How much exercise does my dog need?</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="border" style="flex:1 1 33.33%; height:400px; margin-bottom:10px; text-align:center; padding:10px 10px;">
    <img src="https://images.petsmartassets.com/is/image/PetSmart/ARTHMB-GoDogGoCrateCarrierGateOrKennel-20160818?$AR1104$" style="width:100%; height:70%; position:relative;">
    <a href="#">
      <h6 style=" color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.6); font-weight:900; font-size:12px; margin-top:10px; ">HEALTH & CARE</h6>
    </a>
    <h5 style="font-weight:600;">How much exercise does my dog need?</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks I fixed it but there is another problem now, my rows are two elements instead of the three elements per row, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you misspelled it with a `w` in `flew-wrap:wrap;` should be `flex-wrap:wrap;`

Then you can/need to drop `flex-flow:row;`, it is the default, but is also set the `nowrap` back, being positioned *after* the `flex-wrap` property in the style.

Finally, to fit 3 items in a row, you need to subtract margin/padding from the set width, i.e. something like this `flex:1 1 calc(33.33% - 30px);`

*Note, may I also recommend you switch to classes and external CSS, as having them inline is so much more difficult to manage and more error prone as it is harder to follow.*

*Note 2, `calc()` in the `flex` shorthand doesn't work in IE, there you need to use the longhand `flex-basis`, i.e. `flex-basis: calc(33.33% - 30px);`*

Stack snippet

```html
<div class="border" style="width:100%; height:auto; position:relative; display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap; justify-content:flex-start;">
  <div class="border" style="flex:1 1 calc(33.33% - 30px); height:400px; margin-bottom:10px; margin-right:10px; text-align:center; padding:10px 10px;">
    <img src="https://images.petsmartassets.com/is/image/PetSmart/ARTHMB-HowMuchExerciseDoesMyDogNeed-20160818?$AR1104$" style="width:100%; height:70%; position:relative;">
 <a href="#"><h6 style="color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.6); font-weight:900; font-size:12px; margin-top:10px; ">HEALTH & CARE</h6></a>
    <h5 style="font-weight:600;">How much exercise does my dog need?</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="border" style="flex:1 1 calc(33.33% - 30px); height:400px; margin-bottom:10px; margin-right:10px; text-align:center; padding:10px 10px;">
    <img src="https://images.petsmartassets.com/is/image/PetSmart/ARTHMB-HomeToRoamFindTheRightDogForYourApartment-20160818?$AR1104$" style="width:100%; height:70%; position:relative;">
    <a href="#"><h6 style="color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.6); font-weight:900; font-size:12px; margin-top:10px; ">HEALTH & CARE</h6></a>
    <h5 style="font-weight:600;">How much exercise does my dog need?</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="border" style="flex:1 1 calc(33.33% - 30px); height:400px; margin-bottom:10px; text-align:center; padding:10px 10px;">
    <img src="https://images.petsmartassets.com/is/image/PetSmart/ARTHMB-GoDogGoCrateCarrierGateOrKennel-20160818?$AR1104$" style="width:100%; height:70%; position:relative;">
    <a href="#"><h6 style=" color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.6); font-weight:900; font-size:12px; margin-top:10px; ">HEALTH & CARE</h6></a>
    <h5 style="font-weight:600;">How much exercise does my dog need?</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="border" style="flex:0 1 calc(33.33% - 30px); height:400px; margin-bottom:10px; text-align:center; padding:10px 10px;">
    <img src="https://images.petsmartassets.com/is/image/PetSmart/ARTHMB-GoDogGoCrateCarrierGateOrKennel-20160818?$AR1104$" style="width:100%; height:70%; position:relative;">
    <a href="#"><h6 style=" color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.6); font-weight:900; font-size:12px; margin-top:10px; ">HEALTH & CARE</h6></a>
    <h5 style="font-weight:600;">How much exercise does my dog need?</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this works really well but now there i another problem, the fourth element now stretches to fit the whole row lol

Comment: @gabogabans Yes, the _flex-grow_ value 1 does that, change `flex:1 1 calc(33.33% - 30px);` to `flex:0 1 calc(33.33% - 30px);` ...

Comment: thanks, thanks for all this. This completely solved the issue.